# Get local system time in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a Django app that interacts heavily with other legacy databases. These other databases all use local time, not UTC. I understand Django's time zone support as well as the recommendation to always use UTC time except with interacting with a user. In this case, I really just need Django to give me the system date/time.

In settings.py I have

```
USE_TZ = False
```

And when I run `date` from the linux command line I get (for example):

```
Tue Mar 15 17:03:42 MDT 2016
```

Also when I open a regular (non-django) python shell and run

```
import datetime
str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

I get

```
'2016-03-15 17:04:55.182283'
```

But when I run the same commands from a Django shell `(python manage.py shell)` I get a time one hour earlier:

```
'2016-03-15 16:07:10.949269'
```

Is there some way that I can get a datetime object that has exactly the system time, ignoring any other time zone magic?

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood your query, but can't you just use time.time() to get the system time?

Comment: I think my use of system time is incorrect, apologies. What I mean is that when it's 5pm in my time zone both a regular python shell and the system command 'date' tell me that it's 5pm, but in a Django shell I get 4pm. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 11):

You'd want to use `django.utils.timezone`, specifically:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime, now

# get now datetime based upon django settings.py TZ_INFO
localtime(now())
```

Comment: I've found another way around this, but just to follow, this didn't work in my case. It might if I turned `USE_TZ` on for Django, but when I run the code above I get: `ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime` (The 'other way around this' is basically just to not rely on the time provided by the django app at all, didn't find a way to get django to give me the right time.)

Answer (score 1):

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/):

> How do I interact with a database that stores datetimes in local time?
>
> Set the TIME_ZONE option to the appropriate time zone for this
>   database in the DATABASES setting.
>
> This is useful for connecting to a database that doesn’t support time
>   zones and that isn’t managed by Django when USE_TZ is True.

Set `USE_TZ=True` so that django would use a timezone-aware datetime objects internally.

Set `TIME_ZONE` in the `DATABASES` setting, to accommodate the legacy databases. Django will convert your datetimes to the appropriate timezone automatically i.e., to get the current time it is enough:

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
```

Note: `datetime.now()` returns a naive datetime object. Don't use it.

Comment: I tried this as well, even with the correct time zone set I still get a time that is one hour prior to what I get from a non-django python shell using datetime.now(). What I really want in this case is a naive datetime object, and I guess I'm also genuinely curious why a django shell does anything different with datetime.now() (with USE_TZ off) than a regular python shell.

Comment: I should add - I'm not _only_ concerned with adding / reading time properly from the legacy database, I also need to compare entries from that database with the current time. For example, I need to load objects from the database that were created within the last ten minutes. If I can't get a datetime object that matches the timezone of the legacy database then I can't craft a query that reliably gives me objects from the last X minutes.

Comment: @user1309114 : 1- do you get the wrong time in the db? Or you just printed `timezone.now()` and decided that it is wrong? 2- you shouldn't use `datetime.now()` and therefore its value is irrelevant 3- as I already said: django will convert your timezone-aware datetime objects automatically e.g., to get X minutes in the past: `dt = timezone.now() - timedelta(minutes=X)`. If you pass that value to the db; it should be converted to TIME_ZONE timezone.